# Is there an analogous word to "quadrants" but used when something is divided into nine pieces?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, mathematics

If you take a rectangle and divide it into four equal pieces with two perpendicular lines, you have created quadrants:

[image]

But what if you divide the rectangle into nine equal pieces with two sets of two mutually parallel lines like this:

[image]

Is there a name for these pieces? An example sentence would be:

> The dart has struck the middle ______.

If there are six pieces they can be called sextants, and if there are eight pieces they can be called octants, but the word "nonant" doesn't seem to exist, at least not with this meaning.

edit: I'm specifically looking for a mathematical term to refer to the area that the rectangle is divided into, so a word analogous to "quarter" but referring to nine pieces doesn't answer my question. (See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/whats-the-usage-difference-between-quarter-and-quadrant).)

Comment: The dart has struck the middle square.

Comment: Urban Dictionary lists this meaning for 'nonant', but I'd want to see it in OED (other respectable dictionaries seem to omit it, as you suggest).

Comment: "Square" in this case is not analogous to quadrant, because it neither implies there being a certain number of pieces nor that something has been divided. A better fit would be "section" but I was hoping there was a good word that indicated one of nine pieces of a whole as pictured.

Comment: OED lists *octant,* but not *nonant, decant, undecant* or *duodecant.* I didn't look any further. *Decant* is listed as a verb, of course. This would suggest that the number of historical uses of *nonant* is vanishingly small.

Comment: I tried looking up the possible smaller odd divisions, "septant/heptant", "pentant/quintant" and "triant/treant" and only found "quintant" which was a 17th century instrument similar to a sextant but based on an angle of 72 degrees rather than 60. My guess is that "quadrant", "sextant", "octant" and, to some extent "quintant" were words which were useful in some version of general speech and so became established whereas the others were not generally useful and so did not become established.

Comment: The shape formed by two sets of mutually parallel lines is called  *octothorpe*; it does have 8 points.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octothorpe

Comment: A question asking for specialized terminology will almost almost certainly be better-asked of specialists, and if you're at the point where you are distinguishing between *quarter* and *quadrant*, I really think you're better off consulting a math teacher than an English teacher, say, [Maths.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sudoku solvers use *nonet* to refer to the grid.

Comment: In geometry, a quadrant technically refers to "each of four parts of a space divided by two lines or planes at right angles". And an octant is used with three planes for 3D space. There are no middle parts. But you could certainly use "nonant" in a general sense, as you sometimes hear "octants of a pizza", etc. There is no official term though, which would be nice. Since it's easier to say "the first nonant" than the "upper-left corner". Though it's a catch-22 since you also need to clarify the numbering. eg, in geometry the quadrants go counter-clockwise from upper-right.

Answer (score 7):

Consider ***[ninth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ninth)***, which means

> each of nine equal parts into which something is or may be divided.

It is used to refer to the kind of section you're after in [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=TcfLCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22middle%20ninth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3gIrlyuDPAhXB2B4KHfoVCw4Q6AEIUDAI#v=onepage&q=%22middle%20ninth%22&f=false) mathematical text, albeit with scare quotes. Also, "middle ninth square" is used [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=H85WUaD9f5cC&pg=PA148&dq=%22middle%20ninth%20square%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv7Yqpy-DPAhXDFh4KHTHcC3IQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22middle%20ninth%20square%22&f=false).

In your sentence:

> The dart has struck the middle ninth.

Comment: Yes, but reading that sentence you would probably think: "the middle what?"  :)